# Will this prototype class be created once only by Spring containter?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Since beans in Spring are by default a singleton will just a single instance of the prototype class be created if it's caller is a singleton  :

```
@Service
MySingletonClass
{
    new MyInstanceClass
}

@Scope("prototype")
MyInstanceClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
If you inject the prototype in the singleton it will happen only one time, because Spring will "pull" the prototype from the context only one time.

```
@Service
MySingletonClass
{
    @Autowired
    private MyInstanceClass;
}
```

Notice that if another beans uses the prototype bean, this will create another instance.

Notice that in your example creating the object with `new` will not interact with Spring framework. This object will not be in the context and you will not be able to use the spring  features on it.